# How to preserve tabs from textarea POST data

Tags: php, html, whitespace

This is a simple question; I will make it simple.

So I've got a `<textarea name="textarea"> in a <form method="POST">`

```
<?php
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

echo nl2br($textarea);
```

Solves maintaining the NEW LINES,

But how do I maintain TABS?

tab2tab() or something?

Comment: Here, let me Google that for you :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703967/preserving-tabs-in-post-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, not designed for this specific use, you can do:

```
$textarea = str_replace("\t", "     ", $_POST['textarea']);
```

Or if you want the HTML equivalent of a space:

```
$textarea = str_replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $_POST['textarea']);
```

Comment: More recently I discovered `&emsp;`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `nl2br` at all, that is more an issue how you tell the browser what to do with all these whitespace:

```
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($textarea), "</pre>";
```

and that's it. See the [`<pre>` HTML tag<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre) which also tells you the [`white-space` CSS<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) if you're interested.

Comment: <pre> was my solution. Excellence.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace tabs with 4 `&nbsp;`s or wrap the tab in `<pre></pre>` tags.